# LinkageError in eclipse CDT plugin that using OSGI

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, classloader, eclipse-cdt, linkageerror

I'm writing eclipse CDT plugin on windows.
I want to write code to an existing file in a project, but I need the code to be formatted automatically. I googled and googled, and found this solution:

```
CodeFormatter formatter = ToolFactory.createDefaultCodeFormatter(null);
TextEdit formatEdit = formatter.format(CodeFormatter.K_UNKNOWN, source, 0, source.length(), 0, null);
IDocument dc = new Document(source);
formatEdit.copy();
formatEdit.apply(dc);
System.out.println(dc.get());
```

In order to get this code working(at least partially), I added the following imports:

```
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.ToolFactory;
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.formatter.CodeFormatter;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.Document;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEdit;
```

and the following libraries in the class path and in the plugin.xml runtime definitions:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/org.eclipse.cdt.core_5.6.0.201402142303.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20140110-1610.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.100.v20130513-1956.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/org.eclipse.osgi.services.source_3.3.100.v20130513-1956.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/org.eclipse.osgi.source_3.9.1.v20140110-1610.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/org.eclipse.osgi.util_3.2.300.v20130513-1956.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/org.eclipse.osgi.util.source_3.2.300.v20130513-1956.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/org.eclipse.text_3.5.300.v20130515-1451.jar"/>
```

I was sure that with so much dependencies, the code will work - but now i'm debugging, and getting the  following exception at runtime:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/eclipse/text/edits/TextEdit"
```

I saw this topic is discussed already, but I myself - didn't find out the solution.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Most Eclipse plugins will only run as part of an Eclipse RCP because they rely on a large amount of initialization done when the RCP starts.

Comment: thanks, but I didn't understand what i can do if this is the reality?

Comment: Sorry I think I may have misread the question. If this is an Eclipse plugin you should be able to get this to work. Have you added all these plugins as Dependencies in the MANIFEST.MF editor? Just adding things to the class path is not correct for a plugin.

Comment: Yes, I added them to MANIFEST.MF and to runtime classPath :(

Comment: You should not add the plugins to the runtime classpath there should just be an entry `<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins"/>` which Eclipse will add.

Comment: I think this is not the problem. I used a lot of jar in my plugin in the past. do you know if there is any conflict among the jars I mentioned above? I know that there is a known issue with OSGI jars and the error I'm getting. I think my classpath file and my MANIFETS.MF file are okay. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88988/discussion-between-user1835297-and-greg-449).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. As @greg-449 answered, I had to add the wanted jar to the Dependencies in the MANIFEST.MF.
thanks!!